# How to get indices of valid values of numpy masked array

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf4

I have a netCDF4 dataset representing multiple matrices of the same dimension (551, 146), one matrix (`M1`) contains longitude values, another matrix (`M2`) contains latitude values. Each matrix is a numpy masked array.

Given a lon/lat tuple, `(A, B)`, I want to get the matrix indices (`lon, lat`) where value `A` matches in `M1` and value `B` matches in `M2`.

I thought I could represent the indices with:

```
lon_idx, lat_idx = np.mgrid[:lon.shape[0], :lon.shape[1]]
```

and two matrices of same shape where one have all values set to `A` and the other have all values set to `B`.

Then I am hoping to somehow combine these matrices and end up with an array of `lon`, `lat` indices where the values matched.

What is the idiomatic way to do this in numpy?

Comment: .. Try `np.ix_`?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE], including the output you're looking for.

Comment: @Divakar I think I would need more than that hint to understand how to solve my problem. I've tried using `np.ix_`, but it takes 1-d arrays, and I have matrices, i.e 2d arrays..

Comment: Try printing `np.where(M1 == A)` and see what you get. You should get the indices you need.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to SnoopJeDi on #python @freenode who found the solution for me:

```
In [58]: np.argwhere((lon == lon[250][145]) & (lat == lat[250][145]))
Out[58]: array([[250, 145]])
```